# WordPress will not force SSL for the life of me

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

Hate to complain but I've spent like 2-3 hours working on trying to secure my WordPress site via SSL. I can successfully browse to my site via HTTPS, but I always get mixed content. I've tried several plugins, but there are still resources that are pulling images via HTTP. If I tried to browse to the URLs of those images manually, my web browser actually switches the URL to HTTPS, so I'm not sure why the site loads the images under HTTP but browsing to the images manually forces it over HTTPS. Very Confusing.

I've tried adding this in the .htaccess file of my root directory, so that all requests to the subdirectory /wp-content/ are forced over HTTPS, but it still does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I add this into the .htaccess file, reload the site, inspect element, I still see numerous links in here with http.

I've also tried HTTPS Easy Redirection, which forces HTTPS on everything but then results in a redirect loop. Still no luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. It seems to just be the images.

Comment: did you change your website address and site address to the https ?

Comment: Sure did. The WordPress URL and Site URL from within WordPress's dashboard. The site loads over HTTPS just fine, it's just that there's a bunch of mixed content that I cannot seem to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

What you have setup so far works, but does not address the root issue. As a matter of fact the .htaccess redirect is overkill.

Your Wordpress configuration needs to be edited. Go to your settings>general, ensure that the Wordpress Address Url and Site Address Url are https. It's that simple. You also need to edit any hard coded content urls to https.

You could use some wacky plugin to mutate your links but I would not advise it. But it won't work all the time. That will depend on how your content is constructed.

If you want to play it safe, whenever your add a resource link to content simply omit the protocol like this: `://example.com/...`. That scenario works well with content generated by Visual Composer and the likes.

Comment: I've done exactly this, and I actually removed the information from .htaccess since it wasn't working. As I browse the site and inspect elements, I'm seeing a lot of things in here that are http://, some which are from plugins. Is there not a more easier way to just simply redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS without the redirect loop? I'm not sure why the redirect loop even exists after inspecting its traffic in burp suite.

Comment: Some of your resource files are hard coded in your content. You need to go through every one of them and change them. That happens especially if your content is abstracted with plugin such as Visual Composer.

Comment: Gotcha. So sounds like it's best for me to try getting this done manually. Wonder if I can just do a quick query in the database.

Comment: I would not do a query. Simply because the content is stored as serialized object, so don't even bother. If you edit them they will break.

Comment: Any suggestions for a plugin that includes insecure content but doesn't store it in the database? I almost feel like I have to manually go into the plugin itself and search for it.

Comment: The answer is no. When you are adding a resource to your content through Visual Composer, you have to pay special attention to the protocol you want to use, or just simply don't use a protocol like this: ://example.com

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL is successfully installed in your server then use this plgin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

This will works for you...

Note: Take backup of your website and database first then proceed with the above plugin.

Thanks